# Get relationship from another relationship with Eloquent and Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

I try to get Address with Country's name, which belongs to InvoiceData. Invoice Data belongs to Personal or Business Profile. Last condition was made with **morphTo()** Laravel's feature.

Simplified db structure:

```
personal_profiles:
id, name

invoice_data:
id, address_id, invoiceable_id, invoiceable_type

addresses:
id, country_id, postal_code, city

countries
id, name
```

Then models:

```
class UserProfile extends Model
{
    public function invoiceData()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(InvoiceData::class, 'invoiceable');
    }
}
```

```
class InvoiceData extends Model
{
    public function imageable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function address()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Address::class)->with(Country::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Address extends Model
{
    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Country extends Model
{
    public function address()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Address::class);
    }
}
```

And the Controller:

```
public function getPersonalInvoiceData()
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = \Auth::user();

        /** @var UserProfile $profile */
        $profile = $user->userProfile;

        /** @var InvoiceData $invoiceData */
        $invoiceData = $profile->invoiceData;

        /** @var Address $address */
        $address = $invoiceData->address;
        //$address = $invoiceData->address()->with(Country::class)->get();

        $responseData = [
            'name' => $user->name,
            'surname' => $user->surname,
            'address' => $address,
        ];

        return response()->json($responseData);
    }
```

There is no problem with get address:

```
"address": {
        "id": 1,
        "country_id": 171,
        "city": "Foo City",
        "postal_code": "00-100",
    }
```

But I don't know how to "replace" country_id with related name using Eloquent. As you can see, I tried to use with() on but I got the exception with message: `Call to undefined relationship [App\\Models\\Country] on model [App\\Models\\Address]`. I thought that relations I mentioned are enough. For what did I forgot?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use class in "with" there should be the relation name but I think you don't want to use with method because it will get all countries when you call get method.

All you have to do is:

```
$address = $invoiceData->address->load('country');
```